# Why do transfers between your own accounts WITHIN the same bank take a business day to clear?

Tags: banking, money-transfer

Why is it that when you e.g. transfer money between your savings and checking account at a bank in the U.S. (say Bank of America), it takes a business day for the transaction to clear?

I understand why this would be the case for inter-bank transfers, but I don't understand why this is the case for intra-bank transfers.

Comment: If this bothers you, consider switching banks.  Some banks do these transfers instantly.

Comment: @BrenBarn: How would I figure out which banks do this instantly without actually opening an account and trying it out?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know of a surefire way.  You could find forums where such a question might be appropriate, or ask friends who use different banks.  You could also ask banks directly.  (I use USAA and it does transfers between my accounts instantly.)

Comment: Because the bank make money on the 'float' - the money that's in the process of being transferred?  It's certainly not true of all banks, at least if you include credit unions - mine does transfers in real time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on your bank. My credit union clears intra-account transfers immediately. The delay therefore is based on bank policy.

It is possible that in the system the accounts are not really linked and so it treats transfers between accounts that you own and accounts between people the same. And further in the case of your bank that they decided to have s one day hold. I believe that'll have heard some banks advertise that you can electronically transfer money to another account holder at the same bank in just 15 min.

I would also make sure that you are selecting immediate transfer instead of a future date transfer. Mine has those as two different options and if you select the other, you just select the date of action to be at least one in the future.

Comment: +1 But yes it's definitely an immediate transfer, not a future date. I also don't think it's a problem with them being "linked"... it just seems to be a bank policy I guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad in this case it's more of lousy technology systems than policy.

Answer (score 4):

For most banks this is not the case.  Transfers within the bank are usually instantaneous.

It is not uncommon for banks to draw out the length of transactions because while the money is "transferring" or "settling" it is actually sitting on the bank's balance sheet, being lent out but not earning any interest.  A good deal for them when you aggregate over the millions of customers they have.  Your bank may be trying to squeeze a few pennies of interest out of you.

Delays in transactions also allow their fraud team the flexibility to investigate transactions if they want to. Normally they probably don't but if the bank delays all transactions, then those being investigated will not be aware of it.

Comment: This is how PayPal makes its money.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned BoA. I have had BoA accounts for about ten years. All of my transfers between accounts are immediate. I have never had to wait with BoA.

Scottrade Accounts are the worst in this respect. Once I had to wait 8 days. PayPal come in a close second for making you wait.

Comment: If it's immediate then what does [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pdIxS.png) mean?

Comment: As I have worked in IT shops I can explain how the technology works to make a transfer from one account to another immediate. But I suspect that is not what you want to know. I do not know why your transfers are not immediate. Were they opened in different countries? Were they opened in different states? Were they different kinds of accounts? Do you live in the United States? Are you a natural born citizens of the United States? Is anyone listed on the accounts with you? Are those other people natural born citizens of the United States?

Comment: Here's an easier question. When you make a transfer yourself, do you see the screenshot I sent you? Does it say "processing" or no? And how do you interpret it?

Comment: I did not see the screenshot until now. My only interpretation is that the location in which you opened the accounts is not, yet, updated with the same account management software as the locations in which I have opened accounts. I have had accounts from Texas, Kansas, and Missouri. So my questions still stand. From where did you open these accounts? Do you live in the United States? Are you a natural born citizen of the United States? Do you have anyone listed with you on the accounts? If so, are they natural born citizens of the United States?

Comment: @Mehrdad would you care to answer my questions?

Comment: Well not really, since that's personal information I don't want to reveal here (but no, my situation isn't weird, it's not that). I'm still waiting for you to mention whether you see the same thing as I showed you on the screenshot in your own account when you attempt to make a transfer. You said you didn't see the screenshot until yesterday and then interpreted it for me, which doesn't address my question of what *you* see immediately after you make a transfer. Does yours not say "processing"/"pending"/etc.? If not, then what *does* it say for you immediately after you initiate a transfer?

Comment: For someone who values _his own_ privacy, you are asking me to reveal a lot of my own sensitive information. But I will play along. Here is what I see… [*screenshot*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ligbg779mgtywqz/BoA_xfer.jpg?dl=0) (click on link)

Comment: Huh? o.O I never asked or intended to see your confirmation number, actual dates, or anything like those -- I was only asking if it shows pending or cleared or processing or something else... which was already in my own screenshot. The page you show doesn't actually show what I want to know either, because it's a confirmation that the transaction was initiated, not that it finished. If you'd like to actually track this down, go take a look *online* at your recent account overview (the same screen that I took my screenshot on) and note what you see. I'd be surprised if it actually says cleared.

Comment: As my previous screenshot said: transfers made after 10:45pm are not available until the next day. No, I do not see what you see in the list of accounts. But when I examine the detail of the account to which I made the transfer this is what I see… [*screenshot2*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fymraaf5iqj8vos/BoA2_xfer.jpg?dl=0) (click on link)

Comment: @Mehrdad is it the case that you are initiating the transfer after 10:45pm, or on a weekend? Whenever I make transfers it has been before 10:45pm on a weekday, and the funds are immediately available.

Comment: Yeah, it's the very word *"processing"* that you see that I'm referring to. The last time I tried it was on a weekend, but I thought I'd seen it during plain daylight transfers too. My question therefore was precisely that: does it say processing for an entire business day when the funds are supposedly immediately available? Shouldn't it be processed immediately?

Comment: In IT it is common to allow for a 'window' of time for 'batch pricesses'. During this window of time things like transfers may be postponed. An hour and 15 minutes is a very reasonable time window. As problems with the batch processing are fixed by real live people and as employees of a bank do not work on Saturday or Sunday, it is reasonable to have to wait until Monday for your transferred money to be available.

Comment: From what I've observed it's like that until the *end* of the next business day, not just the beginning. So are you saying the money *isn't* actually available instantaneously even if you submit it during work hours? If so then that contradicts when you said they are available immediately...

Comment: Until this, most recent, transfer I made *every* transfer has been _immediately_ available. My wife would call me (on a weekday, prior to 10:45pm) and ask me to transfer money into our family expense account. *Immediately* after my transfer she would have access to those transfered funds. My guess is that you have transfered money after 10:45pm,or on the weekend. This most recent transfer has been the only time I have ever experienced the 'processing' message.

Comment: Hm, I'll try it again in the middle of the day and see what happens... somehow I feel like that's not the issue. Thanks for the info anyhow. +1

Comment: I see the same result for a transfer at 5:03 PM (didn't remember to do it earlier): it says "processing". Is it still too late in the day?

Comment: 5:03pm is prior to 10:45pm so it was not too late. I have often transferred funds from savings to checking late in the evening on a weekday. The transfered funds have, for me, always been immediately available. I do not know why it does not work that way for you. At this point, only BoA can answer the question of why the transfered funds are not immediately available.

Comment: I believe "immediately available" does not mean "cleared". They may let you withdraw it before it has cleared. Does that solve the issue? In your case it has probably always been "processing" and not cleared, but you've never noticed because it hasn't affected your ability to withdraw.